# CqlSolrQueryExecutor: Undefined name x in selection clause

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, datastax

I'm using DSE with Solr and ran into a problem whenever I query via CQL using an 'AS' to assign a value which is not defined in the schema.

eg:

```
    select f_2 FROM d881 WHERE solr_query='f_2:1';
```

Would return results. But doing:

```
    select f_2, token(f_n) AS fk FROM d881 WHERE solr_query='f_2:1';
```

Would yield:

```
    Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.
```

Checking the logs I can see this error:

```
    ERROR [Thrift:7] 2015-03-21 02:59:58,272 CqlSolrQueryExecutor.java (line 202) java.lang.RuntimeException: Undefined name fk in selection clause
```

I understand It's because Solr isn't aware of those fieldnames, But I don't know how to configure it to just ignore them.

Comment: DSE Search doesn't currently support aliases (i.e. AS), nor it supports functions such as token() or count().

Comment: Yeah, I already figured out that part. going to do some restructuring around it. Thanks.